# looking for better solutions awk or perl: avoiding piping xargs etc

Tags: perl, bash, awk, pipe, xargs

I had to parse files in which are listed the eigenvectors of a square matrix matrix in a seven columns file format, into a square matrix in which each eigenvector is a column of the matrix

```
Eigenvector file: COVAR
   72   72
   42.27674   53.43516   43.10335   43.43889   53.15094   43.77146   43.17536
   52.49170   45.07565   42.10424   52.75460   45.74721   41.66882   52.21836
   47.00361   40.21403   51.86627   47.05245   39.75512   50.92583   47.83411
   38.36019   50.61541   48.00747   37.56547   51.66199   48.72199   36.29018
   51.70312   48.54869   35.35773   52.59045   49.19493   34.14085   51.90543
   49.78376   33.43961   52.55997   50.66576   32.13812   52.14743   51.17284
   31.02647   52.41422   50.19470   30.02426   51.60068   50.14591   28.86206
   51.70417   49.28895   27.52769   51.49614   49.94867   27.52460   50.99136
   51.12215   26.37751   50.74786   51.93507   25.23025   50.04549   51.26765
   25.46212   49.27591   50.30035   24.47349   48.61017   49.51955   23.64720
   49.41136   48.60875
 ****
    1     3.28044
    0.06504   -0.20409   -0.08035    0.04603   -0.02034   -0.02343    0.03885
    0.14025    0.01970   -0.00569    0.11391   -0.05271   -0.00874    0.25005
   -0.02425    0.03969    0.13327    0.01054    0.09958    0.20857    0.08647
    0.13883    0.12003    0.12859    0.05634    0.06415    0.02570    0.07466
   -0.06541    0.04636    0.01246   -0.13691   -0.04270    0.03791   -0.15341
   -0.02595   -0.01027   -0.15604   -0.08393   -0.00526   -0.16938   -0.09027
    0.01573   -0.25999   -0.09350    0.01121   -0.24367   -0.01033    0.03059
   -0.31268   -0.00040    0.02074   -0.17927   -0.01689   -0.02183   -0.03912
   -0.01481   -0.03982    0.10507   -0.03446   -0.06896    0.20946   -0.00450
   -0.17669    0.17617    0.08755   -0.21143    0.25313    0.12818   -0.13896
    0.16625    0.06539
 ****
    2     1.17147
    0.05028    0.24209    0.07571    0.07015    0.26226    0.10552    0.09788
    0.15535    0.10020    0.06248    0.07167    0.09337    0.06555   -0.05258
    0.07777    0.05163   -0.08617   -0.01580    0.05087   -0.17374   -0.06483
    0.03157   -0.18854   -0.12423    0.02388   -0.15753   -0.07304    0.00221
   -0.12406   -0.11678   -0.00030   -0.07568   -0.07783   -0.00225   -0.10201
   -0.09521    0.00373   -0.10066   -0.06755   -0.00386   -0.10808   -0.08343
   -0.01420   -0.03899   -0.11123   -0.06186   -0.02282   -0.11633   -0.07596
    0.03656   -0.14599   -0.07542    0.13621   -0.11299   -0.07350    0.22728
   -0.02254   -0.07473    0.32577    0.01167   -0.09106    0.17148    0.10912
   -0.01607    0.00303    0.19984   -0.01223   -0.16824    0.28827   -0.00879
   -0.23259    0.16630
 ****
   3 et cetera ....
```

I managed to solve my problem as I could, with a lot of pipes... this is an extract of my script that also extracts the eigen values (the number next to the natural numbers under the `****` )

```
local dimensions=$(awk 'NR==2 {print$1}'  ${ptraj_eigvect[$k]}) #in the second line of the file it is written the dimension of the rotation matrix
#Ptraj produces a file in seven columns format
#                        ||
#                        \/
if [[ $((${dimensions} % 7 )) == 0  ]]
then
       local -i n_rows_eigvect_ptraj=$(( ${dimensions} / 7 ))
else
       local -i n_rows_eigvect_ptraj=$(( (${dimensions} / 7) + 1 ))
fi
#        headers          matrix         ****
#          ||   |||||||||||||||||||||||  ||
#          \/   \/\/\/\/\/\/\//\/\/\/\/  \/
awk 'NR>'$(( 2 + ${n_rows_eigvect_ptraj} + 1 ))' && NR%'$(( 2 + ${n_rows_eigvect_ptraj} ))'==2' ${ptraj_eigvect[$k]}  >${eigval_file}

awk 'NR>'$(( 2 + ${n_rows_eigvect_ptraj} + 2 ))' && NR%'$(( 2 + ${n_rows_eigvect_ptraj} ))'!=2 && NR%'$(( 2 + ${n_rows_eigvect_ptraj} ))'!=1' ${ptraj_eigvect[$k]} | xargs printf "%s\n" | awk '($0=$NF x)&&ORS=NR%'${dimensions}'?FS:RS' | awk -f ${script_PA}/transpose.awk >${rotmatr_file}

 if [[ $(wc -l <${rotmatr_file}) != ${dimensions}  ]] || [[ $(wc -w <${rotmatr_file}) != $(( ${dimensions} * ${dimensions} ))  ]]
 then
       echo 'ERROR!!!' 
       exit 1
  fi
```

the transpose.awk file is [here](http://www.e-reading.org.ua/htmbook.php/orelly/unix2.1/sedawk/ch13_09.htm)

I edit as requested

my script produced as 72 x 72 square matrix here I write just the first 2 columns You can see that the numbers correspond with the numbers after `1     3.28044` and `2     1.17147`

```
0.06504 0.05028
-0.20409 0.24209
-0.08035 0.07571
0.04603 0.07015
-0.02034 0.26226
-0.02343 0.10552
0.03885 0.09788
0.14025 0.15535
0.01970 0.10020
-0.00569 0.06248
0.11391 0.07167
-0.05271 0.09337
-0.00874 0.06555
0.25005 -0.05258
-0.02425 0.07777
0.03969 0.05163
0.13327 -0.08617
0.01054 -0.01580
0.09958 0.05087
0.20857 -0.17374
0.08647 -0.06483
0.13883 0.03157
0.12003 -0.18854
0.12859 -0.12423
0.05634 0.02388
0.06415 -0.15753
0.02570 -0.07304
0.07466 0.00221
-0.06541 -0.12406
0.04636 -0.11678
0.01246 -0.00030
-0.13691 -0.07568
-0.04270 -0.07783
0.03791 -0.00225
-0.15341 -0.10201
-0.02595 -0.09521
-0.01027 0.00373
-0.15604 -0.10066
-0.08393 -0.06755
-0.00526 -0.00386
-0.16938 -0.10808
-0.09027 -0.08343
0.01573 -0.01420
-0.25999 -0.03899
-0.09350 -0.11123
0.01121 -0.06186
-0.24367 -0.02282
-0.01033 -0.11633
0.03059 -0.07596
-0.31268 0.03656
-0.00040 -0.14599
0.02074 -0.07542
-0.17927 0.13621
-0.01689 -0.11299
-0.02183 -0.07350
-0.03912 0.22728
-0.01481 -0.02254
-0.03982 -0.07473
0.10507 0.32577
-0.03446 0.01167
-0.06896 -0.09106
0.20946 0.17148
-0.00450 0.10912
-0.17669 -0.01607
0.17617 0.00303
0.08755 0.19984
-0.21143 -0.01223
0.25313 -0.16824
0.12818 0.28827
-0.13896 -0.00879
0.16625 -0.23259
0.06539 0.16630
```

Since I am trying to learn awk and maybe in the future perl I am kindly asking you please to teach me how to write an awk or perl script that performs the same task

thank you very much for your attention

Comment: I'd like to help you out, but I don't have a clue what an *eigenvector* is, or if that's important information.

Comment: I agree with TLP, AND it would simplify our helping you if you include    example output from your sample input (thanks for formatting your message so well!). Good luck.

Comment: I edited. Sorry for poor clarity, btw it is not necessary to know what an eigenvector is. I just want to parse this data file to create a square matrix dim x dim where dim is equal to the first field on the second line of the data file; and whose columns are the numbers listed after the second line after `****`.

Comment: you can forget about the lines between `Eigenvector file: COVAR` and `****` I do not need them at all

Comment: Do you mean that the `1     3.28044` section refers to the first vector, `2     1.17147` to the second vector, and so on, and you simply want them transposed to regular columns, instead of in 7 columns?

Comment: ¡Yes! The lines after  `1 3.28044` and `2 1.17147` and so on refer to the 1st 2nd 3rd ... Nth vectors. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Worked on this for a while, didn't come up with anything very pretty, but the code below seems to work, despite it being rather clunky. It assumes your data is completely uniform, and does not care about headers.

The positive side is, if you change `<DATA>` to `<>`, it will work on your data file with:

```
> script.pl input > output
```

That is assuming your data file has the same formatting as your example, and that your vectors appear in numerical order.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my @data;
my $tmp;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^\*+/) {                  # or some other way of separating vectors
        push @data, $tmp if $tmp;  # push buffer to array
        <DATA>;                    # discard header
        $tmp = "";                 # reset buffer
    } else {
        $tmp .= $_;                # buffer a new line
    }
}
push @data, $tmp;                      # push remaining buffer onto array
@data = map { [ split ] } @data;       # split string into array
for my $num (0 .. $#{$data[0]}) {
    say join " ", map $data[$_][$num], keys @data;
}


__DATA__
****
1     3.28044
0.06504   -0.20409   -0.08035    0.04603   -0.02034   -0.02343    0.03885
0.14025    0.01970   -0.00569    0.11391   -0.05271   -0.00874    0.25005
-0.02425    0.03969    0.13327    0.01054    0.09958    0.20857    0.08647
0.13883    0.12003    0.12859    0.05634    0.06415    0.02570    0.07466
-0.06541    0.04636    0.01246   -0.13691   -0.04270    0.03791   -0.15341
-0.02595   -0.01027   -0.15604   -0.08393   -0.00526   -0.16938   -0.09027
0.01573   -0.25999   -0.09350    0.01121   -0.24367   -0.01033    0.03059
-0.31268   -0.00040    0.02074   -0.17927   -0.01689   -0.02183   -0.03912
-0.01481   -0.03982    0.10507   -0.03446   -0.06896    0.20946   -0.00450
-0.17669    0.17617    0.08755   -0.21143    0.25313    0.12818   -0.13896
0.16625    0.06539
****
2     1.17147
0.05028    0.24209    0.07571    0.07015    0.26226    0.10552    0.09788
0.15535    0.10020    0.06248    0.07167    0.09337    0.06555   -0.05258
0.07777    0.05163   -0.08617   -0.01580    0.05087   -0.17374   -0.06483
0.03157   -0.18854   -0.12423    0.02388   -0.15753   -0.07304    0.00221
-0.12406   -0.11678   -0.00030   -0.07568   -0.07783   -0.00225   -0.10201
-0.09521    0.00373   -0.10066   -0.06755   -0.00386   -0.10808   -0.08343
-0.01420   -0.03899   -0.11123   -0.06186   -0.02282   -0.11633   -0.07596
0.03656   -0.14599   -0.07542    0.13621   -0.11299   -0.07350    0.22728
-0.02254   -0.07473    0.32577    0.01167   -0.09106    0.17148    0.10912
-0.01607    0.00303    0.19984   -0.01223   -0.16824    0.28827   -0.00879
-0.23259    0.16630
```

Answer (score 1):

for an awk-solution try the following. Save these commands in a file s.awk:

```
/\*\*\*/{i++;accInd=0;next}
(i>0){for (k=1;k <= NF;k++){
        I=k+accInd
        a[i,I]=$k
    }
    accInd=accInd+(k-1)
}
END{for (n=3;n<=I;n++){
       for (m=1;m<=i;m++){
           printf "%f\t", a[m,n]
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

Then run from the command line this command:

```
$ awk -f s.awk file
```

HTH Chris

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly I think this AWK script will do the job, I've tried to make it easy to read and understand, hence the rather verbose script:

```
####
# Use like:
# 
#  awk -f transpose.awk <Eigenvector file>
#
#  This script assumes that all Eigenvectors in the file, have the same number
#  of values. The script will output all Eigenvectors into columns e.g if three
#  Eigenvectors it will produce three columns of values.
#
####

BEGIN {
  # Keeps track of the number of Eigenvectors
  currentEV = 0;
}

# Signifies a new Eigenvector (EV)
$1 == "****" {
  newEV = "true";
  transpose = "true";
  next;
}

# Get the EV's number
newEV == "true" {
  newEV = "false";
  currentEV = $1;
  currentEVCol = 0; 
  next;
}

# Add all the values on the line, for the current EV, into the EV array
transpose == "true" {
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    ev[currentEV,++currentEVCol] = $i;
  }
}

END {
  # Loop through the array and print EV's ou in columns
  for (i=1; i<=currentEVCol; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=currentEV; j++) {
      printf ev[j,i] " ";
    }
    print "";
  }
}
```

For a succinct version copy the following into a file called transpose.awk:

```
skip { skip = 0; next; }

$1 == "****" {
  EV++; EVC = 0; skip = 1;
  next;
}

NF && EV {
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    EVA[EV,++EVC] = $i;
  }
}

END {
  for (i=1; i<=EVC; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=EV; j++) {
      printf EVA[j,i] " ";
    }
    print "";
  }
}
```

And call like `$ awk -f transpose.awk file > transposedFile`

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for coding in c++, you could use [Boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) or [flex/bison](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.16/16.07/UsingFlexandBison/index.html).

Comment: sounds interesting it would be really nice performing regular expression jobs in c++ ... if only I knew C++ ;-) I am just a nob xD !
I would be very happy if I could have the time to learn serious programming... may be little by little...

Comment: From wikipedia:  "...It is now also used to mock newbies, or newcomers, on web sites... " :-(

Comment: I wasn't mocking you. It was a genuine compliment. Your code looks impressive to me.

Comment: ^_^ thanks ! It is also fast enough for my needs but I would really like learning a way to perform the same task with a single perl or awk script without piping...
Anyway, are there some situations when piping is the most computationally efficient solution?

Answer (score 0):

Rather similar to TLP's, but a little cleaner in my opinion. Also keeps eigenvalue in separate array. As he said, you can change `<DATA>` to `<>` and run as `scriptname.pl mydata.dat` (you can then remove the `__DATA__` tag and everything after it too).

It uses additional module `Array::Transpose` to do the transpose (install with `cpan` command). The `Data::Dumper` module and its `Dumper` function is used for visualization. The 
`grep { length }` bits remove empty elements found by `split`, this probably could be eliminated by stripping the leading whitespace, but this seemed more robust.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Array::Transpose;

my $row = -1;
my @eigen;
my @data;

while( <DATA> ) {
  if (/\*+/) {
    #increment row number
    $row++;
    #next line is eigenvalue, keep it in @eigen
    my @line = grep { length } split( /\s+/, <DATA>);
    push @eigen, $line[-1];
    # move on to next line
    next;
  }
  next if $row < 0; #skip first block

  push @{ $data[$row] }, grep { length } split( /\s+/ );
}

my @transpose = transpose(\@data);

print Dumper \@eigen;
print Dumper \@transpose;

__DATA__
Eigenvector file: COVAR
   72   72
   42.27674   53.43516   43.10335   43.43889   53.15094   43.77146   43.17536
   52.49170   45.07565   42.10424   52.75460   45.74721   41.66882   52.21836
   47.00361   40.21403   51.86627   47.05245   39.75512   50.92583   47.83411
   38.36019   50.61541   48.00747   37.56547   51.66199   48.72199   36.29018
   51.70312   48.54869   35.35773   52.59045   49.19493   34.14085   51.90543
   49.78376   33.43961   52.55997   50.66576   32.13812   52.14743   51.17284
   31.02647   52.41422   50.19470   30.02426   51.60068   50.14591   28.86206
   51.70417   49.28895   27.52769   51.49614   49.94867   27.52460   50.99136
   51.12215   26.37751   50.74786   51.93507   25.23025   50.04549   51.26765
   25.46212   49.27591   50.30035   24.47349   48.61017   49.51955   23.64720
   49.41136   48.60875
 ****
    1     3.28044
    0.06504   -0.20409   -0.08035    0.04603   -0.02034   -0.02343    0.03885
    0.14025    0.01970   -0.00569    0.11391   -0.05271   -0.00874    0.25005
   -0.02425    0.03969    0.13327    0.01054    0.09958    0.20857    0.08647
    0.13883    0.12003    0.12859    0.05634    0.06415    0.02570    0.07466
   -0.06541    0.04636    0.01246   -0.13691   -0.04270    0.03791   -0.15341
   -0.02595   -0.01027   -0.15604   -0.08393   -0.00526   -0.16938   -0.09027
    0.01573   -0.25999   -0.09350    0.01121   -0.24367   -0.01033    0.03059
   -0.31268   -0.00040    0.02074   -0.17927   -0.01689   -0.02183   -0.03912
   -0.01481   -0.03982    0.10507   -0.03446   -0.06896    0.20946   -0.00450
   -0.17669    0.17617    0.08755   -0.21143    0.25313    0.12818   -0.13896
    0.16625    0.06539
 ****
    2     1.17147
    0.05028    0.24209    0.07571    0.07015    0.26226    0.10552    0.09788
    0.15535    0.10020    0.06248    0.07167    0.09337    0.06555   -0.05258
    0.07777    0.05163   -0.08617   -0.01580    0.05087   -0.17374   -0.06483
    0.03157   -0.18854   -0.12423    0.02388   -0.15753   -0.07304    0.00221
   -0.12406   -0.11678   -0.00030   -0.07568   -0.07783   -0.00225   -0.10201
   -0.09521    0.00373   -0.10066   -0.06755   -0.00386   -0.10808   -0.08343
   -0.01420   -0.03899   -0.11123   -0.06186   -0.02282   -0.11633   -0.07596
    0.03656   -0.14599   -0.07542    0.13621   -0.11299   -0.07350    0.22728
   -0.02254   -0.07473    0.32577    0.01167   -0.09106    0.17148    0.10912
   -0.01607    0.00303    0.19984   -0.01223   -0.16824    0.28827   -0.00879
   -0.23259    0.16630
```